# Betti numbers of non-singular minimal complex projective threefolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

If we consider non-singular minimal complex projective threefolds is there a computable bound on $b_3$ in terms of $b_1$ and $b_2$? Or on $b_2$ in terms of $b_1$ and $b_3$?

Answer (score 5):

There exists complex threefolds with bounded $b_1$ and $b_2$ but unbounded $b_3$: just take the degree-$n$ hypersurface in $\mathbb{CP}^4$. (Actually any 3-dimensional [complete intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_intersection) with bounded number of equations and increasing degree suffice.)

There exists complex threefolds with bounded $b_1$ and $b_3$ but with unbounded $b_2$.

Let $X$ be the [Cartwright-Steger surface](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1631073X09003987) (a complex projective surface with Hodge diamond a $3$ surrounded by 8 $1$s). Let $Y_n$ be an $n$-fold covering of $X$. All the Hodge numbers of $Y_n$ are bounded except $b_2$. Take the product of $Y_n$ with $\mathbb{CP}^1$ and the resulting threefolds have all Hodge numbers bounded except $b_2$.

Comment: For the second example, you may as well take the product of a high degree surface in $\mathbb P^2$ with $\mathbb P^1$. But, with either choice, it might not be minimal in the strongest possible sense (it's not the unique minimal model of its birational equivalence class because of the $\mathbb P^1$-bundle).